# Regex - Capture all from single line after last occurrence of a character

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture just the postcode part of an address - it will always appear after the last comma. I do not want to include any new line text nor any spaces before or after the postcode.

This is the sample text:

```
UID:20230106T092159-yourdelivery@dpd.co.uk
DTSTAMP:20230106T092159
LOCATION:110 My Address, London, SW1A 1AA
DESCRIPTION:My Shop
URL;VALUE=URI:https://www.www.myshop.com
SEQUENCE:0
```

I have come this far up to now:

**[^,]*$**

Which grabs the following:

[image]

I simply want to grab **SW1A 1AA** with no spaces before or after

Comment: How about: `[^,]+$` This matches the last sequence of non-commas on the line.

Comment: If the Format is always the same why not: `^LOCATION:.*,\s?(.+)$` the last parenthesis are the capturing group you want: https://regex101.com/r/hcnyOu/1

Comment: Add `\n` as exception: `[^,\s][^,\n]*$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is capturing the zip code and everything else out of that specific line? https://regex101.com/r/y33PLq/1 (I've learned a lot from your inputs so I always test it :) )

Comment: What about a verbose pattern like `[A-Z0-9]{4,} [A-Z0-9]{3,}$`?

Comment: You might be better of matching more than just the postcode. For example `^LOCATION:.*, *(.*)$` only matches lines that start with `LOCATION:` and store everything after the last `,` (plus optional spaces) inside capture group 1. This does require you to have the `m`ulti line flag enabled, so `^` and `$` match the start/end of a line. And have the `s`ingle line flag disabled, so `.` isn't allowed to match newline characters.

Comment: https://snipboard.io/gt8L4Q.jpg - @JorgeCampos not sure if you've used make.com before but the solution doesn't appear to be working on there (no output)... any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like it is working, I think you need to actually use whatever this parse provides you to use the "capturing group" if the green portion of the text is what you need it seems working. No not familiar with make.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use a verbose pattern like

```
[A-Z0-9]{4,} [A-Z0-9]{3,}$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ozJsCJ/1).

The pattern matches four or more uppercase ASCII letters/digits + space + three or more uppercase ASCII letters/digits

You can precise it depending on further requirements, e.g. `[A-Z]{2}[0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z]{2}$` (see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ozJsCJ/2))